# Is there a way loading an existing page under a fake url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to rewrite an existing path page to a fake directory.

www.website.com/company/events -> fake path, it doesn't exist but it should load /events/ page.

www.website.com/events

Is there a way to do it in Wordpress?

This is what I tried in .htaccess but it does't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/events/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*               /company/events/    [L]
```

P.S: I want to mention the /events/ page is generated by a WP plugin called Events Calendar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?company/events/?$ /events
```

An alternative would be an alias:

```
Alias /company/events /events
```

You obviously need to integrate this with the wordpress generated rewriting rules, something we cannot really help with. Especially since you did not post those...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).